# In Firestore, how do I determine the UID of the newly created user and set that UID as the document name?

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, uid

Currently, I'm using the email as the document name but I'd like to use the UID instead. I tried using "firebase.auth().currentUser.uid" but that retrieves the UID from the last user.

```
try {
      setError("");
      setLoading(true);
      await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
      await db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(emailRef)
        .set(
          {
            firstName: firstNameRef.current.value,
            lastName: lastNameRef.current.value,
          },
          { merge: true }
        )
```

Comment: Hello, can you please share your complete code so we can see the function `signup()` and var like `emailref` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `function signup()` and variables `emailRef` but you can try this.
You can get the UID of newly created user from userCredential object.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(async (userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
      firstName: firstNameRef.current.value,
      lastName: lastNameRef.current.value,
    }, { merge: true })
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you